# Accessing our web app on the stock Android 4.1 and 4.2 browser

Tags: android, browser, http-status-code-403

So I am currently having this problem of trying to open up our web app on the official stock Android browser for Jelly Bean. I don't know how well I can elaborate this problem, but I will try my best.

For devices that run ICS or older, on any browser (stock, firefox, chrome) we can type in the URL for our web app, get taken to the login page, login, and view everything fine.

For devices that run Jelly Bean (4.1 and 4.2), if we type in the url into the **stock browser**, we get the following:

[image]

However, if we use **Chrome** or **Firefox**, its fine.

It's odd that we get this error because I am already authenticated on our network, and I only try to access the login screen so no other authentication would be required.

Our web app grabs information from a server, and it doesn't seem to be a problem on the server side.

So it seems like the culprit is the stock browser in Jelly Bean, and I tried looking up if there were any changes to the stock web browser from ICS to Jelly Bean, but I couldn't find anything yet.

Has anybody come up with an issue like this, or is aware of any big changes (maybe related to security?) that were made to the stock android browser on Jelly Bean?

EDIT: This web app is not available externally. Currently we have only tested internally where you would have to be connected to our internal network.

EDIT2: Just checked with Dolphin Browser and the same thing happened... so I'm really lost now as I am even less sure that it has something to do with the 4.1+ stock browsers. Also, something else that makes me feel even more lost is that, I just checked on the galaxy SIII's stock browser on 4.1.2 and the page loads fine...

EDIT3: Good news, further investigation has been done by our devs and apparently this is the problem:

> the default browser adds an extra header to the request that makes our server think it is an ajax request and rejects it because the rest of the request is not actually an ajax request... This bug is caused because the default browser in Android 4.1+ has added a new header to all requests "X-Requested-With: com.android.browser".

So I'm guessing the Dolphin HD browser does this as well... further investigation is being done so will get back to this and put up an answer

Comment: Can you paste your html code of the html page which is giving this error?

Comment: How can I check the source on the browser?

Comment: Not on the browser. Don't you have the html code of the page which you are trying to load ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to paste that up where anyone can see. It's a product that's already being used by our customers...

Answer (score 0):

According to our devs who did some research:

> the default browser adds an extra header to the request that makes our
> server think it is an ajax request and rejects it because the rest of
> the request is not actually an ajax request...
>
> This bug is caused
> because the default browser in Android 4.1+ has added a new header to
> all requests "X-Requested-With: com.android.browser".

At the moment we can't afford to spend more time trying to find good work around through code for this problem... so we decided to document this as a known issue and suggest people to use Chrome if they have a 4.1+ device